# Why does the solution of a Pell's equation equal zero?

Tags: proof-writing

A Pell's equation is given in the following way:

$
 nx^2 + 1 = y^2
$

According to mathematical rules and the website http://www-groups.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/~history/HistTopics/Pell.html it can also be written like this:

$y^2 - nx^2 = 1$

The equation Bhaskara II uses as an example is:

$y^2 - 61x^2 = 1$

So you have to find *x* and *y*. A solution I found was $x = 226153980,  y = 1766319049$. I tested the correctness of the result with the first version of the Pell's equation (see above):

$ 61x^2 + 1 = y^2 $

$ 61 * 226153980 + 1 = 1766319049^2 \Rightarrow y = 1766319049 $

So the result is correct. Now let's try it with the second way of writing it:

$ y^2 - 61x^2 = 1 $

$ 1766319049^2 - 61 * 226153980^2 = 0 \neq 1 $ (According to [Google](https://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&q=1766319049%5E2-61%2a226153980%5E2))

So the first equation proves the correctness and the second one? What's wrong with my logic or approach that the obviously correct solution equals 0?

Comment: see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Looks like a google rounding error.

Comment: Yes, it looks like google isn't doing arbitrary-precision arithmetic - if you just enter "61*226153980^2," it gives a response of $3.11988298 × 10^{18}$.

Comment: Thank you! It really seems like the precision arithmetic is the problem here. My little C++ program also confirmed me that the result is 1. However, it's always nice to learn things. And this time I learned: Don't trust Google or the calculator for big numbers. ;)

Comment: @Paul: If we casually use a calculator or computer to subtract two large nearly equal numbers, the answer cannot be trusted.

Comment: Wolfram gives the right result . http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1766319049%5E2-61%28226153980%5E2%29

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it seems Google is wrong, for if I paste the same line in my haskell interpreter, I get 1. Although I'm surprised about it, it probably means google does some rounding when numbers get too large.

Comment: I just tested it with Python and my calculator. Python fails completely (probably it misinterprets the results data type) and my calculator shows 0. I'm going to test it now with C++.

Comment: I wonder which version of Python you are using and what statement you are executing?  On Python 2.6.1, 1766319049**2 - 61*226153980**2 gives the correct result 1L.

Comment: @Paul: Maybe you used ^ in Python, it means xor (not exponentiation)

Comment: Yes, I tested it some minutes later with pow. That worked. I know that "^" exists in other languages. But whatever. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 11):

It should be easy to see that Google is wrong in this instance by looking at the last digit of what your answer should be.  The first number ends in 9 which, when squared, will end in 1.  And you're subtracting a multiple of 10.  So just by simple inspection, the answer should have a last digit of 1.

Answer (score 1):

I did not notice this one at the time. Start with
$$ 29718^2 - 61 \cdot 3805^2 = -1.$$
Then use this version of [BRAHMAGUPTA'S IDENTITY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%27s_identity)  that is easily verified by hand,
$$ \left( a^2 - 61 b^2 \right)^2 =  \left( a^2 + 61 b^2 \right)^2 - 61 \left( 2 a b\right)^2, $$
using 
$$ a =  29718, \; \; b = 3805.$$
We find
$$   a^2 + 61 b^2 = 1,766,319,049  $$
and
$$  2 a b = 226,153,980.  $$
So
$$  1766319049^2 - 61 \cdot  226153980^2 = \left( -1 \right)^2 = 1   $$
after erasing the commas.